# How to add custom validation for width when uploading featured image in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, validation, file-upload

Is there a way to check image width/height when it is uploaded as featured image in WP post?

For example, I click 'set featured image', then Media tab opens, I go to 'Upload files' and try to upload a huge image and there is an error like 'The image is too big'.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
add_image_size( 'amolood-featured-image', 90, 590, true );
```

width : 90 
height : 590